# Different between Gnome ODBC vs Microsoft ODBC

Tags: database, odbc

What is the difference between **Gnome ODBC**(Gnome-DB) and **Microsoft ODBC**?

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.gnome.org/libgda/stable/introduction.html has some information on why Gnome Data Access (GDA, otherwise referred to as Gnome-DB) was developed, to try to tackle perceived limitations with ODBC (and JDBC). https://wiki.debian.org/GNOME-DB indicates the Gnome-DB project aims:

> to provide a free unified data access architecture to the DebianGnome project

It tries to fulfill the same role as ODBC, to provide a standard API allowing clients to work with multiple databases with minimal changes.

It perceives ODBC as being:

> mostly limited to the Microsoft Windows environment (even though the
>   UnixODBC project exists and links to some drivers), and the API is
>   quite old and not well integrated into the GNOME ecosystem.

The latest news item from http://www.gnome-db.org/News is currently dated 2015-06-12 for a 5.2.3 maintenance release.

http://www.gnome-db.org/SystemRequirements indicates the software runs on any recent Linux version (as of 2015-01-04) and on Windows, plus other Unix systems.

I can't find information relating to usage levels, but certainly ODBC (whether on Windows or using UnixODBC or iODBC on Linux/elsewhere) seems more popular in my experience, as does JDBC.